# Why React Native view doesn't load using RCTRootView?

Tags: javascript, ios, typescript, xcode, react-native

I am following the React Native [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-existing-apps#the-magic-rctrootview) to load a React Native view from an iOS app.

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, View, Text } from 'react-native';

const TestView = () => {
  return (
    <View>  
      <Text>Hello World</Text>  
    </View>  
  );
};

// Module name
AppRegistry.registerComponent('TestView', () => TestView);
```

I am creating the view from the iOS app as the documentation suggests:

```
guard let jsCodeLocation = URL(string: "http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios") else { return }
let rootView = RCTRootView(
  bundleURL: jsCodeLocation,
  moduleName: "TestView",
  initialProperties: nil,
  launchOptions: nil
)
let vc = UIViewController()
vc.view = rootView
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But when the view controller is presented, I see nothing:

[image]

The integration of React Native in the project is correct. And `index.js` is called when the view controller is presented. But it's not working. Any ideas?

[image]

Xcode logs:

> [native] Running application TestView ({
> initialProps =     {
> };
> rootTag = 51; })
>
> [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C15:1] Socket SO_ERROR
> [61: Connection refused]
>
> [connection] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C15] Client called
> nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
>
> TCP Conn 0x600003104000 Failed : error 0:61 [61]
>
> [javascript] Invariant Violation:
> TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'DevSettings' could not be
> found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native
> binary., js engine: hermes
>
> [javascript] Error: Requiring module
> "node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/InitializeCore.js", which
> threw an exception: Invariant Violation:
> TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'DevSettings' could not be
> found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native
> binary., js engine: hermes
>
> [javascript] Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript
> module method RCTEventEmitter.receiveTouches(). Module has not been
> registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n =
> 10): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog,
> RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter,
> GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient.
>
> A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path
> is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or
> there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js
> engine: hermes
>
> [native] Invalidating <RCTCxxBridge: 0x120507c40> (parent: (null),
> executor: (null))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't running the app in Xcode using Debug-mode.